Finding a non-affine function satisfying symmetry properties
I am looking for an example of a continuous, non-affine function $u\colon X\to \mathbb{R}$ and a continuous, non-negative function $\epsilon\colon X\to\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ such that the following hold (for $x,y,z\in X$ and $\alpha\in(0,1)$):
\begin{align}
&\text{(i) If } u(x)\geq u(y)\text{ then } \epsilon(x)\geq\epsilon(y) \text{ and } \bigg( u(y)-u(z)> \epsilon(y) \implies u(x)-u(z)> \epsilon(x)\bigg)\newline
&\text{(ii) } u(\alpha x + (1-\alpha)y)+\epsilon(x)\geq u(x)\iff u(y)+\epsilon(\alpha y + (1-\alpha) x)\geq u(\alpha y + (1-\alpha) x)\newline
&\text{(iii) } \text{If $ u(x)<u(y)$ then there is $z\in X$ such that either $\bigg(u(z)-u(x)>\epsilon(z)\text{ and }u(z)-u(y)\leq\epsilon(z)\bigg)$ or $\bigg(u(y)-u(z)>\epsilon(y)\text{ and }u(x)-u(z)\leq\epsilon(x)\bigg)$holds.}
\end{align}
where $X\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is any convex set.
Edit: I modified the conditions a little. They now look more complicated, but are a bit less restrictive. Also note that picking $\epsilon$ constant and $u$ affine would satisfy $(i)-(iii)$.

What have you tried so far?  Have you discovered anything about the structure such functions must have?

Unfortunately not, I don't even know where to start really...

I might start by taking X to be a bounded interval in $\mathbb{R}$ so that you can try to draw some pictures and get an understanding for what you're actually looking for.

I'm having trouble with condition (ii). If you take a continuous function $u:X\to\mathbb{R}$ that is not bounded, and set $\epsilon(x)=\phi(u(x))$, where $\phi:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}_{\geq0}$ is monotone, bounded and Lipschitz continuous with Lipschitz  constant $\leq 1$ (like $\phi=\arctan+ \pi/2$) then (i) and (iii) are satisfied.

The hard part of this question for me is unraveling what the conditions even mean visually. May I ask what motivated them?

We can simplify the conditions as follows.
The condition (iii) is equivalent to if $u(x)<u(y)$ then there is $z\in X$ such that either $u(z)-\epsilon(z)\in (u(x),u(y)]$ or $u(z)\in [u(x)-\epsilon(x), u(y)-\epsilon(y))$.
For each $x\in X$ put $v(x)=u(x)-\epsilon(x)$. Then the condition (iii) is equivalent to if $u(x)<u(y)$ then either $v(X)\cap (u(x),u(y)]\ne\varnothing$ or $u(X)\cap [v(x), v(y))\ne \varnothing$.
The condition (i) is equivalent to if $u(x)\geq u(y)$ then $\epsilon(x)\geq\epsilon(y)$ and
$v(y)>u(z)\implies v(x)>u(z)$. This is equivalent to if $u(x)\geq u(y)$ then $\epsilon(x)\geq\epsilon(y)$ and $(v(x)\ge v(y)$ or ($v(x)<v(y)$ and $[v(x),v(y))\cap u(X)=\varnothing$)).
The condition (ii) is equivalent to $u(\alpha x + (1-\alpha)y)\geq v(x)$ iff $ u(y)\geq v(\alpha y + (1-\alpha) x)$.
Since the functions $u$ and $\epsilon$ are continuous, the function $v$ is continuous too. The set $X$ is convex and so connected, and the functions $u$ and $v$ are continuous, so the sets $u(X)$ and $v(X)$ are connected.
Suppose that $u(x)<u(y)$ but $v(X)\cap (u(x),u(y)]\ne\varnothing$. This can happen only if $v(X)\subset (-\infty,u(x)]$, because $v(x)=u(x)-\epsilon(x)\le u(x)$. By condition (ii), for each $\alpha\in (0,1)$ we have $u(\alpha x + (1-\alpha)y)\geq v(x)$.
Now consider the case when $\epsilon$ is the zero function. Then $u=v$, so the conditions (i) and (iii) are satisfied and condition (ii) transforms to $u(\alpha x + (1-\alpha)y)\geq u(x)$ iff $ u(y)\geq u(\alpha y + (1-\alpha) x)$. That is $u(\alpha x + (1-\alpha)y)$ belongs to the segment with the endpoints $u(x)$ and $u(y)$. This can be achieved, for instance, when $u$ is a restriction on $X$ of a composition $f\alpha$, where $\alpha$ is any affine function from $\mathbb R^n$ to $\mathbb R$, and $f$ is any monotonic function from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$.

@LordOfNumbers I updated my answer providing the family of functions $u$ (including non-affine instances) for the case when $\epsilon$ is the zero function.
